# Extend certificate expired date for windows app

Tags: windows, ssl, windows-10

How to extend the expiry date of windows app certificate? We're side loading the app/ The main obstacle is the certificate expires every year which is a bothersome to renew it through GP cause we already have issues in our environment. We would like to extend it for at least 5 years.

I have managed to find technet articles on how to create a code signing certificate but it didnt work. Visual studio doesnt accept the certificate and gives an error message that it is corrupted or invalid. 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/packaging/create-certificate-package-signing#create-a-self-signed-certificate
https://technet.microsoft.com/itpro/powershell/windows/pki/new-selfsignedcertificate

Is there any way to do it easily?

Answer (score 3):

The process is described in [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/msix/package/create-certificate-package-signing), but it is convoluted. There is no "visual" part as "Visual Studio" would suggest.

To sideload an application, it is sufficient to create a self-signed certificate, which means that you trust yourself. There is no trust from a CA (certification authority) involved.

These steps worked for me. The whole process being in PowerShell run as administrator.

**Create the certificate**

```
New-SelfSignedCertificate -Type Custom -Subject "CN=Company Name, O=Company Name Inc., C=CA" -KeyUsage DigitalSignature -FriendlyName "Programming certificate, 50 years" -CertStoreLocation "Cert:\CurrentUser\My" -TextExtension @("2.5.29.37={text}1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.3", "2.5.29.19={text}") -NotBefore (Get-Date) -NotAfter (Get-Date).AddYears(50)
```

1. The `-Subject` item may contain only the `CN=` part, I believe the other bits are optional. `O=` seems to refer to the organization and `C=` the country code.
2. The `-CertStoreLocation` and `-TextExtension` are correct as written (see the documentation). I am not too familiar with what `-CertStoreLocation` really means, as I was not able to find it later, but that is what Microsoft suggests and remains irrelevant to the process.
3. The `(Get-Date)` bits get the current date, and `.AddYears(50)` would be modified to how many years the certificate should last.

The output will display the thumbprint; copy it.

**Export the certificate**

1. Set a password variable (confusingly, the password here is written without quotes).

   `$password = ConvertTo-SecureString -String CustomPasswordYouWouldChoose -Force -AsPlainText`
2. Export the certificate; paste the thumbprint in the "Cert:\CurrentUser\My..." string and choose a file path (in my case, using the C:\ drive worked fine).

   `Export-PfxCertificate -cert "Cert:\CurrentUser\My\YOURTHUMBPRINTHERE" -FilePath C:\ProgrammingCertificate.pfx -Password $password`

**Add the certificate in Visual Studio**

Go to Package.appxmanifest > Packaging > Choose Certificate... > Select from file... > then select your exported certificate.

**Install the certificate on sideload deployment**

Double-click the certificate file > Install Certificate... > Local Machine > Place all certificates in the following store > Browse > **Trusted People** > accept all and the import should be successful. Congratulations, the application is now certified by yourself.

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this, the subject must be same as UWP app's Publisher (package.appxmanifest):

```
New-SelfSignedCertificate -Type Custom -Subject "CN=Something" -TextExtension @("2.5.29.37={critical}{text}1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.3", "2.5.29.19={text}") -KeyUsage DigitalSignature -FriendlyName "Friendly Name" -CertStoreLocation "Cert:\LocalMachine\My" -NotBefore (Get-Date) -NotAfter (Get-Date).AddYears(5)
```

Now export to .pfx and add the thumbprint to the `PackageCertificateThumbprint`

Comment: Using above, when I am trying to use the certificate from Packge.appxmanifest, It is throwing an error: Manifest designer could not import certificate. Manifest designer could not import from file

Comment: This answer greatly lacks in detail. It generally assumes one knows how to run the command and load it into Visual Studio, at which point the answer is not so useful after all. For example, how does one choose the -CertStoreLocation? Also, this must be run in an elevated PowerShell terminal.